# Copy data from private s3 implementation using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-data-factory

I'm looking into using azure data factory for copying files from a S3 bucket that is **not** hosted at Amazon. The current solution that we are using includes some azure functions, a logic app and a web app. With azure data factory this should al be much simpler and easier to maintain.

I've looked into the properties that can be given for an Amazon S3 linked service.

```
"name": "AmazonS3LinkedService",    
"properties": {
    "type": "AmazonS3",
    "typeProperties": {
        "accessKeyId": "<access key id>",
        "secretAccessKey": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "<secret access key>"
        }
    },
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "<name of Integration Runtime>",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    }
}
```

But i do not see a property to set a different host in the documentation.

My question is, is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just a connector for Amazon S3. At least from model layer, there is no property for different host.